# How to put my svg-image in to some <div>? First way with Raphael.js

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm just learning now the Raphael.js. I have ONE questions:
I have an image in .svg format - I create image.svg with AI and then converted here:

http://readysetraphael.com/

I have html file and included raphael.js. 
Tell me please - what I need to do then and how to put my image.svg in some  to display in this div?
And how to create too many divs whis my image.svg, image_another.svg, e.t.c

It very hard for me. Thank for questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean you could try
http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/SVGTOHTML_LIVE.php

Both tools are excellent for getting a project rolling

Have you got more than one SVG?

Comment: O! Thanks very much! But how to remove progress bar? And.. if I need two svg-pic, I need to include many script-files with svg-pictures, yes?

Comment: Trace the div connected to it (look for the word 'progress') and cancel any reference to it to avoid JavaScript errors. Maybe I will get the converter to leave out the progress bar for smaller files.

Comment: Very Thanks for you! Now I'm doing my site whis vector graphic and have another question ))) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456150/how-to-href-my-svg-logo-with-raphael