# How to <href..> my svg-logo with Raphael?

Tags: svg, raphael, href

I'm using a Raphael.js on my site. Take a look logo in the header, please. http://hooche.ru/md2
Code for logo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {    
    var r = Raphael(logo); r.attr({href: "http://google.com/", target: "blank"});
        other vector..
        ...
</script>
```

and html-code for logo^

```
<div id="logo"></div>
```

But now, we have: 1 letter = 1 Google link = very much Google links and empty, not clickable spaces around letters in one svg-logo.

How to do: 1 svg-logo = 1 link to somewhere with no empty spaces,
for example,  div logo have:

```
width: 190px;
height: 67px;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your div with a link, then you won't need the `r.attr()` bit either.

```
<a id="logo" href="http://google.com/"></a>
```

(I would not advise using `target="_blank"` there. It's not the standard behaviour. Let the end user choose.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand why. I had to do something like this:

```
<a id="logo" xlink:href="o-nas.php" title=""></a>
```

> xlink

I read in the documentation.